# Grouped by Reference Field SQQL Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, soql

I am about to make a **GROUP BY**  with reference fields in a **SOQL Apex Salesforce** query, i  get the following message : ***the field can not be grouped in a query call***

The solution i  have is to create  custom fields and update them with a process builder but this solution will help only for the new records and i will have to update all the existing records in the database(more than 1 Million) to fill these custom fields newly created.

What can i can to create a **Group By** with reference field from a parent?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Delivery__r.Beneficiaire__r.ASPO_Master__r.Name, Delivery__r.Beneficiaire__r.ASPO_Master__r.New_ID__c, UM__c,  SUM(Quantity__c)qty 
FROM Item_Distributed__c
WHERE Quantity__c !=0 AND Delivery__r.Beneficiaire__r.ASPO_Master__c !=''
AND Del_Status__c='Delivered'
AND Product__c IN :articleContainersId                                        
GROUP BY  Delivery__r.Beneficiaire__r.ASPO_Master__r.Name, Delivery__r.Beneficiaire__r.ASPO_Master__r.New_ID__c, UM__c];
```

I want to notice that the query is made on a custom object Called Item_Distributed__c with a parent called Delivery which is a child of Account. The field i want to query are from Account.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by reference fields (lookups and master-details). These two should work perfectly fine:

```
SELECT Account.Name, COUNT(Id)
FROM Contact
GROUP BY Account.Name
HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
LIMIT 5

SELECT Account.Owner.Profile.Name, COUNT(Id)
FROM Contact
GROUP BY Account.Owner.Profile.Name
```

You can't use formula fields, maybe some other types. You should check the results of ["describe" call for all fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) in your `GROUP BY`, call `isGroupable()` on them. From apex or API (https://workbench.developerforce.com/ might be fastest) or you could even query it in `FieldDefinition` table...

[image]

Once you identify that formula... If data fix is out of question then think if you can decompose the formula a bit, group by its source fields somehow and then some more steps to interpret the results. It's bit nasty because if somebody edits the formula and doesn't update your query it'll go out of sync.

What if you do it in 2 steps? Grab parents (you tagged `apex` so you could put them in helper `Map<Id, Account>`. And in SOQL group by just the account id? You'd still have to loop through the results and add up rows for different parents but with same formula value but could help a bit?